# autoload database not working in postgres 9.2

Tags: php, codeigniter, postgresql-9.2

I got a problem like, when auto loading my database in system/application/config/autoload.php in codeigniter 1.7.2 and postgreSQL 9.2 I am getting a blank page.

$autoload 'libraries' = array('database')

And when i changed that array('database') to array() I am geting an error

message:Undefined property:xxxx_model:$db

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try by coping this in your autoload.php:

```
 $autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

instead of

```
 $autoload 'libraries' = array('database')
```